# ¿Cómo puedo cambiarle el formato a la hora y que no me salga el siguiente error?

Tags: php, sql, angular

tengo un input en el que meto una hora de entrada y otra de salida, en formato normal "10:30" y "11:30" quiero cambiarle el formato de fecha y hora como se ve en mi código para registrar en bbdd, pero cuando voy a usar format(), hace unos días funcionaba perfectamente... pero ahora no... ahora me salta el error de la imagen:

```
// $time_in ORIGEN 14:00 -> BD -> 2023-03-15 14:00:00
// get dateTime from time php.
// COJO time in y transformo el tiempo en datetime.

$time_in_new_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time_in)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time_out_new_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time_out)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchísimas gracias por leer. Saludos.

Comment: Al construir `$time_in_new_format` le estás pasando los segundos, pero el tiempo no tiene segundos en el dato original, sólo tiene hora y minutos, así debería funcionar: **`DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time_in)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`**

Comment: Dicho eso, ten cuidado con ese código. ¿Dónde está la parte de la fecha? ¿Qué ocurre si alguien entra a trabajar a las 10 de la noche y sale a las 4 de la mañana del día siguiente? No me digas, *no, es que no hay esos horarios*, ok, no los hay, pero no quita que eso cambie en un futuro y cuando eso ocurra habrá tremendo lío en la aplicación. No deberías trabajar ingenuamente con fechas y horas, no ignores nunca la parte de la fecha para guardar datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al construir `$time_in_new_format` le estás pasando los segundos, pero el tiempo no tiene segundos en el dato original, sólo tiene hora y minutos, así debería funcionar: **`DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time_in)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`**

Veamos una prueba:

```
$time_in='14:00';
$time_out='20:00';
$time_in_new_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time_in)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time_out_new_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time_out)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var_dump($time_in_new_format); 
var_dump($time_out_new_format);
```

**Salida:**

```
string(19) "2023-03-22 14:00:00"
string(19) "2023-03-22 20:00:00"
```

Dicho eso, ten cuidado con ese código. ¿Dónde está la parte de la fecha? ¿Qué ocurre si alguien entra a trabajar a las 10 de la noche y sale a las 4 de la mañana del día siguiente? No me digas, *no, es que no hay esos horarios*, ok, no los hay, pero no quita que eso cambie en un futuro y cuando eso ocurra habrá tremendo lío en la aplicación. No deberías trabajar ingenuamente con fechas y horas, no ignores nunca la parte de la fecha para guardar datos.

Veamos un ejemplo del desastre, hoy mismo, un trabajador que entra a las 10 de la noche y sale a las 4 de la mañana:

```
$time_in='22:00';
$time_out='04:00';
$time_in_new_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time_in)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$time_out_new_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time_out)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
var_dump($time_in_new_format); 
var_dump($time_out_new_format);
```

**Salida:**

```
string(19) "2023-03-22 22:00:00"
string(19) "2023-03-22 04:00:00"
```

En la base de datos, se estará registrando que el trabajador salió a las 4 de la mañana del día `22`, pero NO, salió a las 4 de la mañana del día `23`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la respuesta de verdad, de momento los trabajadores sólo se van a dedicar al día como tú bien has dicho que te respondería jaja pero me vendrá muy bien la lección que me has dado para un futuro y lo tendré en cuenta. Saludos!

Comment: @J384 me alegro de que te haya servido. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si la misma ha resuelto el problema, así la pregunta no aparece como sin resolver y podría ayudar a futuros usuarios con un problema similar. Saludos y ten en cuenta lo de la fecha.

Comment: Hecho! Disculpa, soy bastante novato, gracias por todo.